# Why is mean of innovations restricted to zero in definition of VAR process?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, vector-autoregression

The VAR process is defined as:
$$\begin{align} 
\mathbf{y}_t = A_1\mathbf{y}_{t-1} + \dots + A_d\mathbf{y}_{t-d} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t, \quad t \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}$$

where $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t$ is a whitenoise process, in particular $\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_s^T] = \mathbf{O}$, for $s \neq t$.

Why are the innovations restricted to have mean zero?

From looking at section 2.1.1 of [Lutkepohl](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-27752-1) book and the quoted proposition C.9, I do not think this is even necessarily needed for the process to be stable.

Comment: When the process includes an intercept, this is needed for identification. The process you have written must have zero mean, and that is a special case of VAR.

Comment: Also, Lütkepohl defines the VAR as $y_t = \nu + A_1 y_{t−1 }+ ··· + A_p y_{t−p} + u_t$, so that $\nu$ allows for nonzero means of $y_t$. Any nonzero mean of $u_t$ would then also be absorbed in $\nu$.